# How can I clean a URL with PHP for canonical?

Tags: php, meta-tags, canonical-link

Looking into Search Console I fond some duplicated urls

Duplicates url are the same of original URL + g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)

For example:

https://mywebsite.com/my-page/

https://mywebsite.com/my-page/g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)

I try to clean the URL this way for meta canonical but it doesn't seem to work

```
$mycanonicalurl = "https://mywebsite.com" .parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: The second URL doesn't look valid after all. How did you generate it in the first place?

Comment: I did not generate the second URL I found as a "complain" of Search Console as a duplicate of first, Search Console list the url that it is complaining about canonical and duplicate. Server can resolve both since it is a url rewrite

Comment: Then you need to check where this URL is generated in your application. Google won't randomly generate URLs

Answer (score -4):

Firstly you need to find duplicated urls in content site. It is not basic. Search Console can to browse all content of site. For example below i has offered to find regex method:

```php
<?php

$content = '<a href="http://111.com/?asd=1"> as </a sdff <a href="http://111.com/?avsd=21"> sdsad </a>asa <a href="http://111.com/?a=1">s <\/a> adas sad sa</a>  <a href="http://1131.com">sadas sad sa</a><a href="http://1411.com">sadas sad sa</a>  <a href="http://111.com">sadas sad sa</a> ';

$content_urls = preg_match_all('/<a *href="(.+?)">(.+?)<\/a>/im',$content,$matches);

$repeated_urls = [];
echo'<pre>';
$urls = [];
foreach($matches[1] as $url ){
    
    $url = parse_url($url)['host'];
    echo $url . ' ';

    if(in_array($url,$urls)){
        
        $repeated_urls[$url]['url'] = $url;
        $repeated_urls[$url]['count'] = isset($repeated_urls[$url]['count'])?$repeated_urls[$url]['count']+1:2;
            
    }
    
    
    
    $urls[] = $url;
}

print_r($repeated_urls);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Which parts of that code help the OP to resolve their problem?

Comment: I wrote about it . I mentioned every content as $content variable. For every framework or cms developer can adapt self project.

Comment: Why you decrease my reputation ?  I suffered this solution.

Comment: "For every framework or cms developer can adapt self project" - what do you mean by that? Also, please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: Your answer doesn't even try to explain how to handle the duplicated URLs that end with `g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)`

Comment: There showed end of url finished with g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m). He doesnt want  use from it. Additionally Google Seo bots doesnt recognize urls which parsed javascript. That is , you uncorrectly understood and decreased my response.

Comment: "you uncorrectly understood and decreased my response" - did I? If the OP's page currently prints URLs that end with that JS code, how does your code ensure this does not happen anymore? Feel free to add all clarification to your answer by editing it